# monkeyrunner::python::I can't create a file in my disk via monkeyrunner

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, adb, monkeyrunner

First, let me know you my development environment :

Windows 7 x64 NoteBook

Android sdk installed, including adb and monkeyrunner

Python 2.7 on Windows

---

I did script simple python code for test like this :

[ test.py ]

import os

os.system("adb shell ls -l > d:\\ls.txt")

You know this is very simple and there's nothing wrong.

I executed this script on command prompt.

"D:>monkeyrunner d:\test.py"

It always throw this error message like this :

"/system/bin/sh: can't create d:\ls.txt: Read-only file system"

but, it just work well when I type

"D:/>test.py" on prompt.

one more thing,

it does work well too when is on windows7 x86 environment. ( I am x64 )

I can't make sure of the reason why it doesn't work through monkeyrunner.

Someone help me.

T.T

Comment: I've solved this problem by myself. T.T

Comment: then let us now what the solution was. Sounds like a permission issue to me.

Comment: I guess that when you use `"D:/>test.py"` your script runs with python not monkeyrunner interpreter

Answer (score 0):

@htcl

Let me show you my solution.

p = popen('adb shell ls -l').read()

f = open('d:\ls.txt', 'w')

f.write(p)

f.close()

That's all.

Just try. It looks like simple problem but was hard to find solution.

I used the way round

Thank you for your interest!

Have a nice day :)